# How do you group OR clause in WHERE statement using HIVE

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, bigdata

I would like to query by the following

```
(statement1 AND statement2 AND (statement3 OR statement4 ))
```

this is my hive query, I verified that it doesn't work since it only returns statement3, and I know there are case where statement4 is true

```
SELECT 
  cid,
  SUM(count) AS total_count
FROM
  count_by_day
WHERE
  time >= 1435536000
  AND time < 1436140800
  AND(
    cid = '4eb3441f282d4d657a000016'
    OR cid = '14ebe153121a863462300043d'
  )
GROUP BY
  cid
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Is count a real variable name?  Double check that.
2. Also check to make sure your time is a numeric type, probably a bigint.  If it isn't cast it as a big int like this:

   ```
   WHERE cast(time as bigint) >= 1435536000 AND cast(time as bigint) < 1436140800
   ```
3. Try changing your or statement to an in statement.

   ```
   SELECT 
    cid,
    SUM(count) AS total_count
   FROM
   count_by_day
   WHERE time >= 1435536000 AND time < 1436140800
   AND cid in('4eb3441f282d4d657a000016','14ebe153121a863462300043d')
   GROUP BY
   cid;
   ```

Try each change one at a time so you know what the fix is.

Comment: The `in` syntax worked, I am surprised that you can't group logical statement by parentheses

Answer (score 2):

Always learnt to use UNION instead of OR in relational databases. Try and see if union solves your issue.

```
select cols
from table
where statement1 AND statement2 AND statement3

union all

select cols
from table
where statement1 AND statement2 AND statement4
```

Answer (score 0):

Query1:

```
Select A,B,C
From 
                Table1 t1
                Join 
                Table2 t2
                On 
                                T1.field1=T2.field1 OR 
                                T1.field2 = T2.field2
```

Query2:

```
Select A,B,C
From 
                Table1 t1
                Join 
                Table2 t2
                On 
                                T1.field1=T2.field1 

Union 

Select A,B,C
From 
                Table1 t1
                Join 
                Table2 t2
                On 
                                T1.field2 = T2.field2
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, read the question properly.